# Condition induces Null Homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a question in a step of a proof in P. May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" (page 70):

[image]

Why does the condition (iii) imply that if $e \circ g $ null homotopic then also $g$?

Well, (iii) imply that $g$ factorieses over $CS^n$ (the "mapping cone") by $\tilde{g}$, but how does it induce null homotopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a map $g:X\to Y$ which extends to a map $\tilde{g}:CX\to Y$ on the cone $CX=X\times I/X\times\{1\}$ (identifying $X$ with $X\times\{0\}$ in $CX$).  Composing $\tilde{g}$ with the quotient map $p:X\times I\to CX$, we get a map $H:X\times I\to Y$.  Since $\tilde{g}$ is an extension of $g$, $H(x,0)=g(x)$ for each $x\in X$.  Also, since $p$ is constant on $X\times\{1\}$, so is $H$.  So $H$ is a homotopy from $g$ to a constant map.